# Font-awesome icon display issue in Angular4 and Bootstrap4

Tags: angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-4

I used bootstrap4 to display user icon in signup page. It was displayed when I use @angular/cli v1.3.x but I am having this issue after upgrading version @angular/cli to v1.6.6.
Here is the warning when I run

> ng serve

command line in terminal.

```
    WARNING in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"import":false}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./src/assets/css/style.css
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-import: F:\Work\Angular\cryptoview\cryptoview\src\assets\css\style.css:55:1: @import must precede all other statements (besides @charset)
NonErrorEmittedError: (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) postcss-import: F:\Work\Angular\cryptoview\cryptoview\src\assets\css\style.css:55:1: @import must precede all other statements (besides @charset)
    at Object.emitWarning (F:\Work\Angular\cryptoview\cryptoview\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:117:16)
    at result.warnings.forEach (F:\Work\Angular\cryptoview\cryptoview\node_modules\postcss-loader\lib\index.js:149:49)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at postcss.process.then (F:\Work\Angular\cryptoview\cryptoview\node_modules\postcss-loader\lib\index.js:149:27)
 @ ./src/assets/css/style.css 4:14-149
 @ multi ./src/styles.css ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/assets/css/style.css ./src/assets/css/colors/default-dark.css
```

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you post your `style.css`?

Comment: I am sorry. https://plnkr.co/edit/I9QDX9RYswB60N1Awpto?p=preview
This is the style.css

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your `@import` lines at the top. Even, the plnkr you provided gives a warning. Also, you may put these paths into `styles` array in the `.angular-cli.json`. This way, angular will bundle those css files with your style and your users will load them faster or you can have multiple `<link>`s in `index.html`.

Comment: I have a job to solve for AngularJS. Let's discuss about that in chat.

Comment: My skype is freestar1987. Please contact me. Looking to your reply

Comment: "You have to put your @import lines at the top".
This sentence helped me. :)